# Google Apps Script - Spreadsheet linked script w/ onFormSubmit trigger returning empty namedValues

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

**Context**
I have a spreadsheet that has 12 different forms linked to them. These forms will each have a different test, and I need to constantly update each tester's final results sheet with the results of their individual responses to the 12 different forms. The gist of it is: **I need a script on the spreadsheet to do all this work for me**. But I'm having a problem achieving the first step of collecting the form answers that trigger the spreadsheet's `onFormSubmit` event. My problem seems to defy the documentation, so I suspect that I'm misunderstanding something or its a bug.

1. The script is bound to the spreadsheet, not the forms so `e.namedValues` should work.
2. The data isn't showing up blank in the log only; using these variables within the code treats them as empty strings.
3. I'm not sure if getting this data from processing the spreadsheet is a realiable way to ensure all data is being processed. So I need to find a way to process the form responses as they come in.

**Attempted Solution**
Event trigger

```
function createOnSubmitTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("submitTest")
    .forSpreadsheet(answersheet)       //The answer sheet that the form sends results to.
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

submitTest function

```
function submitTest(e) {  
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e.namedValues, undefined, '\t'));
}
```

Execution log:

```
{
    "First Name": [
        ""
    ],
    "Email": [
        ""
    ],
    "Last Name": [
        ""
    ],
    "Timestamp": [
        "6/17/2023 14:50:56"
    ]
}
```

The form has more questions than that, but they're all blank except for the timestamp.

**Standing Problem**
I've done a ton of research on Stack Overflow and the Google forums, but I cannot understand why I cannot get the form answers from my script.

According to [the spreadsheet OnFormSubmit event docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit), I should use `e.namedValues` to access the results of the form that triggered the spreadsheet's `OnFormSubmit` trigger. Using my code below, the `namedValues` correctly have the form question side of the pairs but not the answers; they're always blank.

Am I misunderstanding for the event data should be accessed? Is this a bug, or did I set something up incorrectly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `According to the spreadsheet OnFormSubmit event docs, I should use e.namedValues to access the results of the form that triggered the spreadsheet's OnFormSubmit trigger.` You are referring to the documentation, and it does NOT say that you should use e.namedValues. It is showing that namedValues are one of the Event Objects returned by `onFormSubmit`. Another option is `values`. You can use what ever best suits you. I also suggest that you edit your "Logger" statement to `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` - this will return **ALL** the available Event Objects.

Comment: You have misunderstood an aspect of the installation of the `onFormSubmit` trigger. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onformsubmit) seems to imply that you can/should name the "Response sheet" that is to be triggered. That's NOT correct: in `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();`, `getActive` refers to a spreadsheet object, not a sheet within a spreadsheet. So `.forSpreadsheet(sheet)` simply means "for the active **spreadsheet**". This will be more obvious if you install the trigger manually.

Comment: So you've got 12 forms linked to a single spreadsheet. That's OK because you can use [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) (specifically the `range` object) to determine which form generated the response.  Something like `const formResponseSheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName()` will provide the sheet name for the actual form submission. From there, there are several coding options for how to enable the script to be tailored to each response sheet.